# Change like status with jQuery on a flask app

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask

I am working on a flask web app and I am trying to implement the like comment feature with jQuery so that the page does not have to reload when the like button is clicked. Below are my codes. Any help will be much appreciated.

route:

```
@main.route('/like-comment/<int:id>', methods=["GEt", "POST"])
def like_comment(id):
comment = Comment.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
if comment is None:
    flash('This comment is invalid or has been deleted by the user')
    return redirect(url_for('.home'))
current_user.like_comment(comment)

return jsonify({'result' : 'success', 'like_comment' : current_user.like_comment(comment)})
```

`JavaScript`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.like').on('click', function () {
    var comment_id = $(this).attr('comment_id');
    req = $.ajax({
      url : '/like-comment',
      type : 'POST',
      data : {
        like_comment : current_user.like_comment(comment), 
        id : comment_id
      }
    });

    req.done(function (data) {
      $('#like'+comment.id).text(data.like_comment);
    });
  });
});
```

`HTML`:

```
{% if not current_user.is_liking_comment(comment) %}
  <button class="like btn btn-pill btn-warning btn-xs" comment_id="{{ comment.id }}">
    <span class="icon icon-thumbs-up" id="like{{ comment.id }}"></span> Like
  </button>
{% else %}
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what your question is.

Comment: @Miguel I want user to click the like button on a post and see the like button change from "like" to "liked" on the post. Just as you would click  like on a post on Facebook or twitter. Nothing happens with my current code and I was wondering if you'd have some tips for me> I am trying to use jQuery Ajax to achieve this so that the page does NOT RELOAD

Answer (score 0):

I don't use flask, but I see you're using an attribute "comment_id", is that a Flask thing? Otherwise, you should use "data-"...

In your HTML...

```
<button class="like btn btn-pill btn-warning btn-xs" data-comment_id="{{ comment.id }}">
```

And then in jQuery...

```
var comment_id = $(this).data('comment_id');
```

But I think the problem is that your returning JSON and you haven't indicated that to your $.ajax call...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.like').on('click', function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var comment_id = $(this).attr('comment_id');

        $.ajax({
            url : '/like-comment',
            type : 'POST',
            data : {
                like_comment : current_user.like_comment(comment), 
                id : comment_id
            },
            dataType='json'
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            $('#like'+comment.id).text(data.like_comment);
        });

    });
});
```

Or if you don't want to use Promises...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.like').on('click', function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var comment_id = $(this).attr('comment_id');

        $.ajax({
            url : '/like-comment',
            type : 'POST',
            data : {
                like_comment : current_user.like_comment(comment), 
                id : comment_id
            },
            dataType='json',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#like'+comment.id).text(data.like_comment);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Let me know if it helps...

Comment: yes that's a flask thing. I tried it with the data and nothing happened unfortunately. Do you have an example of how you would do it? It doesn't have to be flask

Comment: That helped a lot. when I click the like button it takes me to a page that displays the son like so {
  "like_comment": null
} but when I go back and refresh the like takes effect. Any idea on how to make it not take me to that url that shows the Json?

Comment: Good to hear!! HAve a nice day and happy coding!

Comment: sorry I mistakenly hit enter, I edited my response, there was a little problem. please see my response

Comment: Probably the default behaviour of the click event. I've edited the answer, check the "event" thing

Comment: unfortunately that did not help.

Comment: Have you added the "event" parameter to the click function line? --- $('.like').on('click', function(event) {  --- I'm asking you this just because is a common mistake... Are you getting any console error?

Comment: yes I added it. I am not getting a console error. I get a status 200. I just noticed that I had a link attribute added to the button when I get the Json as stated earlier. When I take that off, nothing happens on. click

Comment: What's a link attribute? Is that a Flask thing?

Comment: I mean the html "hypertext reference" aka href=""

Comment: Ahh! Ok. You shouldn't have that. Remove it, put an alert inside of the click, another one inside of the done function, and check if it's entering there when you click.

Comment: still no luck :(

Comment: No alerts displayed? Not even the one inside the click function? No errors? Then looks like the problem is that your click event is not being fired.

Comment: probably and I am a beginner, not sure how to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an action to your data object to call the function on the server. See below:

```
data: {
  action: like_comment, //or the name of your function on the server
  like_comment: current_user.like_comment(comment),
  id: comment_id,
},
```